# Multiple notifications from bluetooth low energy devices issues on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have encountered an issue with the bluetooth notifications. I have 2 sensors that I connect to. Each of them has several services, each service has certain characteristics.

I subscribe to one characteristic of one of the services. I do this for both sensors. Each sensor sends packets of data of lengths 12 and 13 bytes  one after another continuously.

I am using a single `BluetoothManager`, a single `BluetoothAdapter`, two `BluetoothGatt` variables and two `BluetoothGattCallback`, each one defined for each ble sensor.

I connect to the first sensor, the notifications come perfectly, very fast 12-13-12-13-12-13... everything fine! After I connect to the second sensor, notifications from second sensor start coming also 12-13-12-13-12-13. But notifications from first sensor start having issues - I see just the 13 data packet. Something like "sensor 1 packet 13 - sensor 2 packet 12 - sensor 2 packet 13 - senor 1 packet 13 - sensor 2 packet 12 - sensor 2 packet 13 - senor 1 packet 13" ... and so on.

Practically, the data packet of length 12 does not come anymore. The app on iOS works perfectly, thus is not a problem on the sensors, but on the Bluetooth Stack.

I tried with https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle - I had this issue. 
Then I implemented the raw solution from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le - I had the same issue. Then I tried the library from https://github.com/NordicPlayground/puck-central-android.

They have tried to manage somehow to issue with threads (overriding many methods and trying to synchronize threads, to avoid concurrent access), but in essence my issue was not solved. Even using their library, I still encounter the same problems (https://github.com/NordicPlayground/puck-central-android/issues/4).

I tried all sort of small hacks, starting manually a new thread on each new notification, adding a small delay / sleep on the thread. All these solutions proved themselves not being a real solution.

I read many many articles on stackoverflow and other sources related to this subject, I spent more than 2 weeks on this issue and could not manage to get a solution.

Did anybody encounter the same issues, trying to get very rapid notifications from 2 ble devices (connected in the same time) in packets of data with different lenghts?

Comment: You may want to add details about the hardware and software versions.  It does sound like an issue with the BLE stack on Android, but what version of Android are you using?

Comment: Can you post the code for your onCharacteristicChanged? You need to extract the value in that callback directly and not in some scheduled handler.

Comment: @Tim Tisdall, I indeed tested in 3 devices and it proved that it is a problem just on one device (Samsung SM-J330F Android 7.0, API 24). But this is not ok not to work on certain devices... This device has BLE, is from 2017 and is pretty good. I tested on a Lenovo S1La40 (Android 5.1, API 22) and on a Samsung SM-G935F (Android 8.0.0, API 26) and it worked on both of them. Do you have more details on why it works on some devices and on others not?

Comment: @Emil, the code is inside onCharacteristicChanged without any scheduled handler. Meanwhile I tested on other devices and it works. It seems to be a problem on just some devices.

Comment: Yes that sounds strange. Maybe you can look at the HCI snoop log to see if the notifications contain the right data in the first place?

Comment: @Emil - You'll quickly find out BLE can have a lot of headaches because not all hardware (or software stacks) work right in all circumstances.  Most work right in the common cases, but fail in weird and wonderful ways in edge cases (such as trying to connect too many devices).  I believe the Google Play dashboard lets you mark particular devices as unsupported so you could try to keep track of which devices don't work right and prevent people using the software on those devices.  Android limits doing lower-level calls, so you're kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I connected to three devices and got data from the characteristics, the data was exposed approximately 20 times per second, then I did not experience any problems with this. I ran into the problem that the phone was losing packets, it seems the problem was in the phone itself. Maybe you have a problem in the phone itself. What is your version of android?

Comment: as I answered above to Tim Tisdall, I realized the same thing, that it is a phone issue. Do you have more insight regarding this? Can you share more details why this might happen?